# SSRS Action URL via javascript:void(window.open...) doesn't work in IE on different computer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, url, reporting-services

I used action url in my SSRS report.

```
="javascript:void(window.open('http://myserver/myGetDocLink/Enter/CreateLink?&rs:command:Render&PID=" & Fields!SURECNO.Value & "&RID=2','_blank'))"
```

But does not open in Internet Explorer on different computers.

Please, Help me.

Comment: Does it produce an error message? Does the URL run on the machine without the JavaScript?

Comment: YES,  it run successfully Report Without Javascript. But the Report not react url With Javascript.

Comment: You can try to check the version of Internet Explorer. If any new update is available for IE than try to install it. Using the latest version of Internet Explorer can help to solve your issue. Ref: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/12dc2499-006a-4588-9f0e-2dd03dcd2168/ssrs-action-url-via-javascriptvoidwindowopen-doesnt-work-in-ie?forum=sqlreportingservices

Comment: Hi @Deepak-MSFT, Thank you for your help. But I want to these explain: I show my that report in other web portal. It doesn't react in here.

Comment: Hi, my problem solved these method: http:///&rs:Command=Render&rc:Toolbar=False